# WCF WebSocketService read cookies

Tags: wcf, cookies, websocket

I have a WCF service (inheriting from WebSocketService) hosted in IIS.
I'm trying to get cookies from the request I'm handling in "OnMessage".

I tried using:
- WebSocketContext.CookieCollection
- HttpContext.Current.Request (Current is NULL)
- OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties

None of them worked.
I'm probably missing something in the web.config file or something else.
I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using WebSockets through WCF? I tried long ago, and it didn't provide anything interesting, just very little functionality. Why not other framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure about this, but enable ASP.NET compatiblity:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And then check `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

The cookies are sent in the HTTP handshake, not with every message.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to get cookie with every message?

Comment: I guess you can check HttpContext each time. Cookies are sent only on handshake, and won't change for the length of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

To get information from the handshake (without enabling aspNetCompatability) you should instead access the `WebSocketContext`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocketcontext?view=netframework-4.8

The `WebSocketContext` will contain all the information sent along with the initial handshake.

Example:

```
var op = OperationContext.Current;
var wsProperties = op.IncomingMessageProperties[WebSocketMessageProperty.Name] as WebSocketMessageProperty;
var wsContext = wsProperties.WebSocketContext;
```

From there you can access `Headers` or the `CookieCollection` properties.
These properties will remain the same for as long as the WebSocket is open.